# Header with three elements, one left, one center, one right

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to develop in HTML and CSS, and despite reading about the box model I am still having trouble with some of the basics of positioning.

I want to create a header navigation bar with three elements - one to the left of the page, one to the right, and one in the center. I want these elements to be inline with each other.

At the moment, they are represented in HTML like so

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <ul class="child">
        <li id="lodestone"><a href="">The Lodestone</a></li>
        <li id="mogstation"><a href="">The Mog Station</a></li>
        <li id="user"><a href="">User Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have then attempted to align them using the 'text-align' property in CSS.

```
.header {
    background-color: #ffd9e7;
    border: black;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#lodestone {
    text-align: left;
}

#user {
    text-align: right;
}

#mogstation {
    text-align: center;
}
```

However, instead of the expected result it produces this.
[The three items are aligned, next to each other, on the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKG4i.png)

Can anyone recommend what css property I should be using to solve this problem? My research has shown there are ways of using float, but other people recommend against it, and when I try I get issues with the text overflowing off the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the ul and lis a width and  (100 ul /30 for li s for example) then they should display correctly

```css
.header {
    background-color: #ffd9e7;
    border: black;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header ul {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.header > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:30%;
}

#lodestone {
    text-align: left;
}

#user {
   text-align: right;
}

#mogstation {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <ul class="child">
        <li id="lodestone"><a href="">The Lodestone</a></li>
        <li id="mogstation"><a href="">The Mog Station</a></li>
        <li id="user"><a href="">User Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added vertical-align:top; but it's excess to requirements, you could take that out..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/oavwy9vo/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, that worked! If you don't mind answering a quick follow up to help my understanding, what is the significance of 30%? It seems to suggest you're making each element have 1/3 of the page width, but wouldn't that be 33.3% ?

Comment: i set the li to classes (cos an id won't inherit from a class normally). I set it to 30 to account for natural browser adding margins and padding. However you can get rid of the default margins and padding by doing the asterisk thing at the top *{margin:0; padding:0;} and adding your own padding and margins to suit.

Comment: you commented when I was still typing.. Welcome to the stack - hours of fun, lol!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a different approach to layout your elements

```css
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the li elements a third of the width?

First make the ul 100% width, you'll also need to ensure there's no padding on the right of the ul as it tends to be automatically added by browsers:

```
.header ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then have each li 33%

```
.header > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Style the rest as required